# Can I save the file chunks in different folders

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

In my project I am using Golang as a server and mongodb as a db, and now I want to limit space for  users  and want to know there is a way to save gridfs chunks in different folders, for example if user id is 123 than create 123 dir and save chunks there.

Comment: gridfs chunks are stored in the database. No folders there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mongodb` does not saving files as a "physical" file, so you can not store it in folders, as the `mongodb` creates `chunks` from file content.
I can offer you 2 ways  to solve your problem

1. you can add 2 different fields in your user document, 1) space and 2) used f.e. and every time when user will upload file you can check file size  and free space , and if it will true than update users fields and save files
2. you can every time check the users file size but if users have a lot of large files than the operation  will take  a lot of time

Comment: JFYI, there's [this button](https://monosnap.com/file/Wcyp12ByNI3DH3Dgy7cgZzWJtZ1T9z.png) in the post editor, which offers markdown help